# I need a faster way to draw images, and render them

Tags: c#, wpf, image, image-processing, graphics

I am working on an app that allows you to paint with images. With every brush stroke, images are drawn to my canvas. I basically have a canvas with a collection of Image controls. Performance is not so good when the number of images increase.

Also, rendering the canvas with RenderTargetBitmap.Render gives me an insufficient memory exception sometimes depending on the number of images on my canvas, and the dimensions of my canvas and images I am painting with.

Is there a solution to this? I can rasterize after each brush stroke by rendering all those images on my canvas, clearing the canvas, then drawing the newly rendered image to the canvas. This would probably take too long though, having to wait in-between every single brush stroke doesnt sound too good.

So what are my options? Am I able to do all this with a WriteableBitmap? Can I add multiple images to one WriteableBitmap, and is it fast? Or is there some library I can use to draw and manipulate (scale, translate, rotate) images?

Here is what I my app currently does by drawing image controls to a canvas:
[image]

**Edit**:
I went ahead and implemented that rasterization technique I described above. Its not too bad actually.

256x256 canvas: http://i.minus.com/iFXnyYg3N3qjx.gif

2048x2048 canvas: http://i.minus.com/i5GId8iM8hU28.gif


The demo was tested on a pretty old pc, that I am targeting to be the minimum requirement. I also tested it on a newer pc and it works fairly smoothly even on 2048x2048. I would still like it to be faster though. I was thinking I could render the canvas on a background thread, but I would have to come up with a way to be able to draw images while the canvas is rendering. Another option I thought about was rendering the canvas in parts on different threads in parallel (if thats possible in C#). So for example, a 2048x2048 canvas could be rendered as four 512x512 sections at the same time. It was also suggested that I learn OpenGL and start from the ground up. You cant make a gui in WPF for an openGL app right?

Comment: not sure if and how it can be applied in your case but have you investigated the Flyweight pattern?

Comment: Is it really necessary to draw a sequence of overlaying images? Or would it be an option to draw the stroke with a tiled brush, as shown in the Remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: have you tried using something from here 
http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: First time hearing about flyweight patter, im looking into it.
Changing the brush step is one of my implemented features, if the brush step is small enough it should overlap, so I cant use a tiled brush unfortunately.
I looked over the source of writeablebitmapex, and it seems adding images to the writeablebitmap is limited. I'll see if it can be used.